# How to transfer Video data using Adaptive Autosar

Tags: middleware, video-processing, autosar

I am working on Adaptive Autosar project, where input data (video) captured from camera sensor needs to be transferred from client machine to server machine, which runs object detection algorithm.
someIP (service oriented middleware over IP) protocol is used as middleware .

Is it possible to share video file using SomeIP protocol?
If No, what is other method to share the video frame?

Thanks & Regards
Astha Mishra

Answer (score 2):

The problem would be, that you would need a very good connection between the two ECUs, and I doubt that even with Ethernet, you can pass the data that fast to keep a certain performance. It might make sense to preprocess the data, before transmitting it somewhere else.

Transmission would be done rather as a byte stream with a streaming protocol, e.g. SomeIpTp, you might think about compression if possible. UDP instead of TCP might be also a good idea, but consider the possible drawbacks of UDP.

Vector seems to provide some MICROSAR module called MICROSAR.AVB module for Audio/Video-Briding.

But make sure, the sensor/camera does not provide the data faster than it can push it out over the network.